# Issue on beveling mesh at intersection of topologies

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology, boolean-modifier

How can I bevel this ? It's a shape that I've attached to a sphere. I tried beveling it before adding the sphere but since it had 16 vertices at point of attachment, I couldn't add it.
[image]

These are the edges that I want to bevel.

[image: Example of edges to bevel]

After the bevel

[image: Example after bevel]

Close-up of vertices after the bevel

[image]

I also tried mean crease but same issue. I actually tried beveling before adding the sphere but was not able to blend them together since the beveled mesh has 16 vertices and couldn't really figure it out.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you upload your file with https://blend-exchange.com/ ? I'm pretty sure your topology is bad somewhere and it prevents you to bevel more than what you showed us.

Comment: blender-exchange doesnt upload the file even tho its only like 1mb @Lutzi

Comment: You have to accept terms and copy-paste link to your question.

Comment: yeah uploaded, it said " file may take some time to process" with a loading bar so i thought i had to click on upload when the loading bar is done loading lol

Answer (score 0):

You could extrude from 4 faces of your sphere:

[image]

Then bevel:

[image]

Create this topology:

[image]

Add this edge loop to avoid the pinching:

[image]

Result with the *Subdivision Surface*:

[image]

For the object you share, maybe remove this edge loop:

[image]

Comment: i tied doing it like that but couldnt get it to work :( here is the file if you are willing to help thank you https://we.tl/t-go0o5uSCGO

Comment: You couldn't get it to work, but at what step do you fail exactly?

Comment: It looks weird with pinches even after adding supporting loops

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [here](https://blend-exchange.com/b/p4kYVOY2/)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, you can perfectly bevel on the second object (don't forget to recalculate the normals, they are flipped): https://zupimages.net/up/24/12/2mh6.gif then rearrange the topology as shown

Comment: i tried the same u did but it is not working properly for some reason i flipped normals too thanks for noticing  https://jmp.sh/s/ERI2McHyXHj5UeGe9VkE

Comment: After bevelling you need to correct the topology with the knife (K) or with some joins (J), see my images

Comment: thank you i think it worked, i have some weird dark shading tho is it bad topology or normal ? https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=24/12/e4sr.png and https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=24/12/wdgp.png

Comment: could you please share your file?

Comment: this is the complete file, its my first model with no youtube tutorial so since you at it and if you want an overview topology feedback is appriciated [file](https://blend-exchange.com/b/zD3S7Dry/)

Comment: See my edit, remove this edge loop, it will make the shape rounder, is it what you want?

Comment: yeah it looks better i really appriciate it thank you, i also subbed to both of ur channels even tho i dont speak french that good but i find ur content helpfull espacilly that baking tutorial :)

Comment: @tukay3 kid hey thanks a lot   ;)   now you need to learn french

Comment: lol i speak un petit peu